# Django dynamodb integration resource not found exception

Tags: django, amazon-dynamodb

First of all I am a fresher in django and `dynamodb`. I followed the https://github.com/gtaylor/django-dynamodb-sessions link and tried to integrate django with DynamoDB to create an api .

I made sure that AWS keys are correct and table can be connected using python and boto but still while running on server i am getting the error;

```
 "DynamoDBResponseError: 400 Bad Request
{'message': 'Requested resource not found: Table: employee not found', '__type': 'com.amazonaws.dynamodb.v20111205#ResourceNotFoundException'}"
```

Comment: Is it possible you are connecting to a different region when running this on Django than you are when you connected via boto?

Comment: I am not sure about it but i am seeing some codes like that any way I am able to connect to the table via boto ConnectionBorg() but it doesn't seems to be a good practice and it takes more time to get the response api (i mean request per section is low for it) while comparing to other db integrations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it my self my db  was connected to a region when i connected that region it work's fine.. :)

Comment: for the sake of completeness, the key to add for region is: DYNAMODB_SESSIONS_AWS_REGION_NAME